# Basic understanding of the Adaboost algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, adaboost

I'm a machine learning newbie trying to understand how Adaboost works.

I've read many articles explaining how **Adaboost** makes use of **set** of **weak** **classifiers** to create a **strong classifier**.

However, I seem to have problem understanding the statement that  "**Adaboost creates a Strong Classifier**".

When I looked at implementations of [Adaboost](http://codingplayground.blogspot.com/2009/03/adaboost-improve-your-performance.html), I've realized that it doesn't "actually" create a Strong Classifier but somehow in the TESTING PHASE figures out on "**how to use set of Weak Classifiers  to get more accurate results**" which in turn acts like a **strong classifier** "**Collectively**".

So technically there is NO **SINGLE STRONG CLASSIFIER** created (but set of weak classifiers collectively act as a strong classifier).

**Please correct me if I'm wrong. It would be nice if someone can throw in some comments regarding this**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A classifier is a black box that receives an input (feature vectors) and returns an output (labeled vectors). So to call something a classifier, you only care about ***what*** it does, and not ***how*** it does it. AdaBoost's classifier can be seen as such black box, so it's indeed a single classifier, even if it uses internally several weak classifiers to produce such output.